# Keras: input with size x*x generates unwanted output y*x

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I have the following neural network in Keras:

```
inp = layers.Input((3,))
#Middle layers omitted
out_prop = layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(inp)
out_value = layers.Dense(units=1, activation = 'linear')(inp)
```

Then I prepared a pseudo-input to test my network:

```
inpu = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

When I try to predict, this happens:

```
In [45]:nn.network.predict(inpu)
Out[45]: 
[array([[0.257513  , 0.41672954, 0.32575747],
    [0.20175152, 0.4763418 , 0.32190666],
    [0.15986516, 0.53449154, 0.30564335]], dtype=float32),
array([[-0.24281949],
    [-0.10461146],
    [ 0.11201331]], dtype=float32)]
```

So, as you can see above, I wanted two output: one should have been an array with size 3, the other should have been a normal value. Instead, I get a 3x3 matrix, and an array with 3 elements. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing three input samples to the network:

```
>>> inpu.shape
(3,3)  # three samples of size 3
```

And you have two output layers: one of them outputs a vector of size 3 **for each sample** and the other outputs a vector of size one (i.e. scalar), again **for each sample**. As a result the output shapes would be `(3, 3)` and `(3, 1)`.

**Update:** If you want your network to accept an input sample of shape `(3,3)` and outputs vectors of size 3 and 1, and you want to only use Dense layers in your network, then you must use a `Flatten` layer somewhere in the model. One possible option is to use it right after the input layer:

```
inp = layers.Input((3,3))  # don't forget to set the correct input shape
x = Flatten()(inp)
# pass x to other Dense layers
```

Alternatively, you could flatten your data to have a shape of `(num_samples, 9)` and then pass it to your network without using a `Flatten` layer.

**Update 2:** As @Mete correctly pointed out in the comments, make sure the input array have a shape of `(num_samples, 3, 3)` if each input sample has a shape of `(3,3)`.

Comment: I don't want to have in input 3 samples of size 3. I want to have one sample of size 3x3. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: `inp = layers.Input((3,3))`means every sample is 3x3 

`inpu = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]) ` (note shape is 1x3x3) means you have 1 sample of 3x3 data

Comment: @today i am forced to follow this: "Alternatively, you could flatten your data to have a shape of (num_samples, 9) and then pass it to your network without using a Flatten layer." Because otherwise there is this error: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @FedericoDorato Possibly you are doing something wrong. Edit your question and add the code which gives this error.